# Pandas importation fails on ipython and Jupyter

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, ipython, python-import

I have been experiencing the following problem with **pandas** for days: I can import pandas when I use **spyder** but it does not work when I use **ipython** or **jupyter**. I have been looking in several directions to solve the problem:

- I have updated **pandas**,
- I have checked that **ipython** and **spyder** have the same *pythonpath*,
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled **spyder**

It still does not work and I get the following error message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d6ac987968b6> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas

/Users/ME/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     29                       "pandas from the source directory, you may need to run "
     30                       "'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C "
---> 31                       "extensions first.".format(module))
     32 
     33 from datetime import datetime

ImportError: C extension: hashtable not built. 
If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 
'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

I see that other people had the same problem but there is no clear answer. Does anyone know the procedure to solve it ?

Comment: This doesn't help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761152/how-to-solve-import-error-for-pandas

Comment: No it does not work. Sadly.

Comment: How did you update pandas? (conda? pip?)  What version?  Does pandas work from an ipython/python prompt?

Comment: @Back2Basics: I have updated pandas using  "pip install --upgrade pandas". I have pandas 0.18.0. Pandas does work from the ipython/python prompt available on spyder BUT it does not work on the classic ipython/python prompt (the one opened from the terminal).

Comment: since you are using anaconda I would suggest using their install tool called "conda".  so try a "conda update pandas spyder ipython"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: the error comes from a value error due to an encoding problem.

It happens quite a lot in python and various questions have been asked about it. Among them, the following link explains it carefully:

[Pelican 3.3 pelican-quickstart error "ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8)

To be short, one only needs to run the following bash code to solve the problem:

```
echo -e "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8\nexport LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```