# How to open .xlsx using python 2.7.3?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to open `.xlsx` file using python for further manual process.
I tried

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'empty_book.xlsx')
```

by importing `openpyxl` module. But it does not open the file rather it just loads the file. Is there any other way to open excel file in python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you want to do with the fille?

Comment: I will be editing it manually.

Comment: What is `editing manually`? Like in Excel? Or setting the cell values?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas` (also you need to install module `xlrd`)

```
import pandas as pd


excel_data = pd.read_excel('empty_book.xlsx')
```

Comment: I am getting following error even if pandas and xlrd is installed                                                                 
 >>> import pandas as pd

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    "the C extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: NaT not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.

Comment: @RadhickaPardessi check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761152/how-to-solve-import-error-for-pandas

Comment: Is there some advantage in using pandas instead of openpyxl?

Answer (score 1):

Import openpyxl

```
>>> import openpyxl
```

Load the workbook that you are trying to read

```
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Empty.xlsx")
```

Give the name of the sheet

```
>>> ws = wb['sheet_name']
```

For looping through values in the excel

```
for row in ws.rows:
        for cell in row:
              print cell.value
```

To edit the values

```
for row in ws.rows:
        for cell in row:
              cell.value = new_value
```

Comment: I don't want values to be printed , rather want to open excel sheet.

Comment: what do you want to do after opening the excel sheet ?

Comment: `ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value = new_value` specify the value which you are trying to change to and the respective row and column value in excel sheet