# Importing Pandas in python always gives an error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python 3.6, windows 7, pyCharm IDE. I keep getting this message when trying to import pandas using `import pandas`.

> File "C:\Users\Seif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 35, in 
>       "the C extensions first.".format(module))
>   ImportError: C extension: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.

I tried some solutions provided on google search but nothing works.

1) checking pip version using this command: `pip -V`

> pip 9.0.1 from c:\users\seif\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
>   packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg (python 3.6)

2) installing pandas using this command: `pip install pandas --upgrade`

> Requirement already up-to-date: pandas in c:\users\seif\appdata\local\programs\p
>   ython\python36-32\lib\site-packages
>   Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil>=2 in c:\users\seif\appdata\loca
>   l\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
>   Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.9.0 in c:\users\seif\appdata\local\prog
>   rams\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
>   Requirement already up-to-date: pytz>=2011k in c:\users\seif\appdata\local\progr
>   ams\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
>   Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5 in c:\users\seif\appdata\local\programs
>   \python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas)

when I run the suggested command `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force` there is no file called setup.py.

so what I missing?

Comment: As suggested in your first message... 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' ?

Comment: You can try to uninstall both pandas and numpy, and reinstall the latest versions of numpy and pandas. Do that from  settings on Pycharm

Comment: possible dup : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761152/how-to-solve-import-error-for-pandas

Comment: when applying this command: python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force

I got this message python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Try uninstalling Pandas and Numpy, then install Numpy and then Pandas respectively!