# How to stream data into Google Cloud BigQuery using Appengine with Python Script-flowing data from API?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, socrata

I've been attempting to stream data from the below api and finding very little success.

https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.cityofchicago.org/8v9j-bter

- Automating a datalab notebook with a shell script is too finnicky
- Using airflow to orchestrate is too finnicky as well
- The below code worked in a datalab notebook, but don't know if the "Context" magic command will work in a regular script.
- Is this even possible in appengine?
- Can someone provide guidance on the other scripts necessary for this run properly?
- Indents for code may be off

main.py script

```
       #install main packages
      !pip install sodapy
     import pandas as pd
     from sodapy import Socrata
     from google.datalab import Context

     #put into dataframe
     client = Socrata("data.cityofchicago.org", None)
     results = client.get("8v9j-bter", limit=2000)
     results_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)

     #flow into BigQuery
     results_df.to_gbq('chicago_traffic.demo_data', Context.default().project_id,
                   chunksize=2000, verbose=True, if_exists='append')
```

App.yaml script

```
     runtime: python27
      api_version: 1
     threadsafe: true

      handlers:
      - url: /.*
       script: main.app
```

cron.yaml script

```
  cron:
     - description: "append traffic data"
      url: /.*
      target: main
      schedule: every 1 mins 
  retry_parameters:
     min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
     max_doublings: 5
```

requirements.txt

```
   pandas==0.22.0
   sodapy==1.4.6
   datalab==1.1.2
   google-api-python-client
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the app.yaml you are using you would be deploying in [App Engine Standard Enviroment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/). When you use the Standard Enviroment you can use any of [these built-in third party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) by adding them to your app.yaml file or you  can use any other third-party library by following the steps in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27).

The problem here is that as stated in the [previous link I shared](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27):

> You can use third-party libraries that are pure Python code with no C
>   extensions,

The pandas library has parts of its code written in C (https://pandas.pydata.org/#library-highlights [How to solve import error for pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761152/how-to-solve-import-error-for-pandas)
), therefore in order to use Pandas you would need to use the [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/).

You’d need to do some modifications in your files in order for your deploy to run. Follow these links to adapt your files to the flexible environment:

- [app.yaml configuration in flexible enviroment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml)
- [cron.yaml configuration in flexible enviroment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml)
- [here you have simple example with an app.yaml, main.py and requirements.txt files.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/hello_world)

!pip install sodapy makes use of the magic command !, [which is something exclusive from some Notebooks environments](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html). You cannot add that line to your main.py file. This operation (pip install sodapy) will be run during the Deployment of the App because you are adding sodapy==1.4.6 to your requirements.txt file.

Instead of adding the Context.default().project_id, you should be able to just add your project_id as a str. When running inside the App Engine Flex authorization shouldn't be an issue. If you want to run it in local remember to use [a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) with the right permissions.

Comment: This was suuuper helpful. Thankfully I was able to finish this incorporating a lot of your feedback already. Let me know if you have any feedback for my post below.

https://github.com/sungchun12/schedule-python-script-using-Google-Cloud

Comment: I'm glad this helped you to finish the github repo. If I have the time I'll try it!