# How to solve pandas import error in pycharm?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I've already install pandas from either the terminal and add `pandas` in pycharm project interpreter. However, every time I run a program which uses `pandas` it keeps reminding me there's an error.

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rabbit/PycharmProjects/NLP/review2vector.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame
  File "/Users/Rabbit/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    "the C extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

I also followed this question's answer [How to solve import error for pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761152/how-to-solve-import-error-for-pandas) But it does not work for me.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Mac OS High Sierra

Comment: If you installed `miniconda`, you have to be sure `pycharm` uses this install of python. The easiest solution is to install `pycharm` too into your `conda` environment, this version should be directly linked to the correct python.

Answer (score 2):

These issues can be easily avoided if you use a virtual environment to install and maintain your Python packages. Please refer to the link here for more information: [LINK](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that numpy is not fully installed. There isn't enough information there to guess specifically what is wrong, but if I was troubleshooting I would use my package manager (pip probably) to uninstall and then re-install numpy and pandas. I would do numpy separately so that I could watch the messages. The numpy page says that they should have pre-compiled wheels available, so it just seems like a version mismatch.

Pycharm lets you install packages into a virtualenv easily and ensure that env is always activated when you open the pycharm terminal (great!) but it also makes it very hard to notice install errors.