# python/Pandas - you may need to run... to build the C extensions first - without cmd

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, python-c-api

I downloaded pandas from PyPI and I installed it (I use Python 2.7). When I try to run a little python script with pandas, I have that error : *ImportError: C extension: DLL load failed: %1 is not a Win32 application. not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.*

I know I can resolve this by typing some code in the *cmd* window ([I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761152/how-to-solve-import-error-for-pandas)) but my problem is that I don't have admin access and I'll never have (so I can't download anaconda and do *conda install pandas*). So I need to find a solution where I can "*force the build of the C extension of pandas*" but without using the cmd window. Is it possible ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your  operating system and how have you installed python?

Comment: The hassle free way is to install anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: I'm working on windows 7 and python 2.7 was already in the office when I came so I don't know how it was installed sorry :/

Comment: I don't understand how to use anaconda when it's downloaded and installed. I saw that the file installed has a lot of modules inside but I don't know how to make my python.exe linked with the pandas module... When I try to run my little script including "import pandas as pd" I still have "No module named pandas" and if I copy-paste the "pandas module" from the anaconda file, right to my Python27 (site-package) I have errors like : "Missing required dependencies (numpy)" etc...